# Sumproduct ranges excluding rows with sum=0 or row containing blank cells

Tags: excel

Here is a sample data set:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
a   20  0   9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   9
a   0   10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10
a   20  10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   18
a   0   10      7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   18
a   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   5   4.5 0   0   18
a   0   10  8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   8
b   0   10  6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
b   10  0   9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5
b   0   10  9   3.5     0   0   0   0   0   0   0
b   0   10  5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   8
b   10  8   6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   10
b   0   15  24  0   5   0   0   0   0   0   5   9
c   0   0   8   0   4.5 0   0   5   0   0   0   0
c   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
c   10  10  27  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
c   5   20  5   0   10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
c   10  10  10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10
d   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
d   10  5   5   0   0   0   0   0   0       5   10
```

I have to calculate the circular vector length (r) of each type: a, b, c and d.
The individuals of each set containing blank or like the second c containing all 0's give error for the formula I am using which forces me to calculate r for each individual first using formula-

For first a (in O column):

```
=IF(OR(COUNTBLANK(B2:M2)>0,SUM(B2:M2)=0),"",SQRT(SUMPRODUCT(B2:M2,B$1:M$1)^2+SUMPRODUCT(B2:M2,B$1:M$1)^2)/SUM(B2:M2))
```

Then for average over all a with:

```
=IF(SUMIFS(O$2:O$20,A$2:A$20,Q2)=0,"",AVERAGEIFS(O$2:O$20,A$2:A$20,Q2))
```

What I need is something to combine both formula so that excel:

1. First checks for matching type: a, b, c, d
2. Excludes rows with blanks or sum=0
3. Sumproduct each remaining row
4. Average over all a's for example

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: cursory glance looks like your formulas are on the right track.  thank you for the sample data.  What do you expect for results? (Sample of results)

Comment: I can not weed out 'all 0' and 'any blank' because the entire data set contain other columns (in my case data for other years) where that may not be the case

Comment: Here is a sample result:

Individual a 
6.906624374 
9.899494937 
7.542472333 
 
14.50168144 
8.895859505 
 
a 9.549226519

Comment: I think your requirements are a bit too complicated for excel formula's. However VBA would be able to solve your problem, are you familiar with VBA?